# This is the error am getting Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in System.Drawing.dll System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid

Tags: c#

I want to display image on picture box in C# from my nodejs service. The solution works in some images and fails in some images. Some images are giving this error which I don't have a clue why it would fail and if I post the same image url on browser it is able to display.
This is my nodejs that is sending image for viewing.

This is the error am getting

> Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in System.Drawing.dll
> System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid. at
> System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(Stream stream)

```cs
public Image GetImage(string id)
{
    string url = "https://localhost:3000/"; // Replace with your URL
    string username = "admin"; // Replace with your username
    string password = "dev12345"; // Replace with your password
    try
    {
        // var cert = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\hms\client_cert.cer");
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
        // ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        string fullUrl = $"{url}scans/{id}";
        Console.WriteLine(fullUrl);
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(fullUrl);
        //  request.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Basic {Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{username}:{password}"))}");
        using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK && stream != null)
            {
                using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                    var imageData = memoryStream.ToArray();
                    var image = new Bitmap(new MemoryStream(imageData));
                    return image;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've fixed your formatting for you. In future, please look at the preview and don't submit if the formatting is a mess.

Comment: Can you confirm that specific images fail every time and others succeed every time?

Comment: `var imageData = memoryStream.ToArray();` <-- This is redundant. You can pass the single `memoryStream` directly into `new Bitmap` - just rewind it first.

Comment: Your code never verifies that the HTTP response from the remote server actually contains a real, valid image file... At the very least you should inspect the response `Content-Type:` header and check for a file-signature in the first few bytes of the downloaded data.

Comment: `catch (Exception e)` <-- Do not catch `Exception` itself - only catch specific Exception subclasses that you expect will be thrown.

Comment: @jmcilhnney could you provide sample code

Comment: @Dai Would you mind help me resolve that error